# Can one change the domain xml configuration file of glassfish 3.1.2.2 while the server is running?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I changed the domain.xml while the server was running and it seems like old configuration has been restored later again. Is it not allowed to change the file directly while the server is running? Does one need to use the admin console in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is not allowed to edit this configuration file manually at all:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/gjjrl/index.html

> Note –
>
> Changes are automatically applied to the appropriate configuration
>   file. Do not edit the configuration files directly. Manual editing is
>   prone to error and can have unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

With dynamic configuration, changes take effect while the DAS or instance is running. The following configuration changes do not require restart:

1) Adding or deleting add-on components

2) Adding or removing JDBC, JMS, and connector resources and pools (Exception: Some connection pool properties affect applications.)

```
3) Changing a system property that is not referenced by a JVM option or a port

4) Adding file realm users

5) Changing logging levels

6) Enabling and disabling monitoring

7) Changing monitoring levels for modules

8) Enabling and disabling resources and applications

9) Deploying, undeploying, and redeploying applications
```

Comment: Ok this is from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/gitzw/index.html and doesn't really answer the question. However the page before said it clearly. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27313044/1184842